# popup link disappearing after 1 click in firefox

Tags: javascript

Below link will be disappear after 1 click only in firefox, how to fix this?

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com','name','scrollbars=1,width=600,height=400')">Open page in new window</a>
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/qyog1syp/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link does not disappear, the problem is that firefox still links to the page in the attribute `href` in this case in the jsfiddle, it's linking to google.com, but google doesn't allow to embed google in an iframe, so you get a blank page in jsfiddle.

if you use `javascript:void(0)` inside your href the link will do absolutely nothing, if you use `#` it will link to a non existing anchor on your page, this is not a problem, but you see it in the address bar of your browser.

You can try this instead:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com','name','scrollbars=1,width=600,height=400')">Open page in new window</a>
```

If you just want to open the link in a new tab instead you can use `target` for this, some old browsers will still open this in a new window:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Open page in new tab</a>
```

Comment: but there is no iframe...?

Comment: in **jsfiddle** there is an iframe, this will lead to a blank page if you test your old code directly in your browser (firefox), you will see that the popup opens and google opens in your current tab

Comment: javascript:void(0) is working as it should...but still i see it when hover

Comment: parent page is fix as it should be when link clicked, thanks

Comment: there is a problem when i click it also opens a new window with popup

Comment: yes because you are opening a popup with `window.open('https://www.google.com','name','scrollbars=1,width=600,height=400')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com','name','scrollbars=1,width=600,height=400')">Open page in new window</a>
```